# Will Selenium help to automate my clients on Android, iOS, OSX and Windows? OSX and Windows are standalone applications

Tags: android, ios, windows, macos, selenium

Will Selenium help to automate my clients on Android, iOS, OSX and Windows? OSX and Windows are standalone applications (something like Microsoft Lync). If not Selenium is there any other free tool to achieve this?
I basically want to run automation across all these clients.

Answer (score 1):

For Web-Browser Automation you can use selenium.

If the website is Made base on AngularJS then you can use protractor. 
http://www.protractortest.org/#/

If the application is standalone then you can use UTP(upgraded version of QTP).
http://www8.hp.com/in/en/software-solutions/unified-functional-automated-testing/

And for mobile automation you can use Appium
http://appium.io/

Hope this answer's your query.
Happy Learning.
Reply to me for further help. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there any way I can use Selenium and QTP together? I mean from say one master machine can I give commands to machine where Selenium works and other machine where QTP works? I basically want to check the working across clients.

Comment: Please tick the answer or upvote it if you are satisfied with my answer. It will help me a lot.

Comment: You cannot use both of them together. QTP is of HP and selenium is of google. Selenium supports many languages while QTP supports VBscript. So i would suggest if it is standalone application use QTP, and if it is Web based try it with IDE that whether we can automate it through selenium or not.

Answer (score 0):

No selenium only helps in automationg web based applications. You can't automate windows based application using selenium. As Krishan Patel has told you, you have to use appium (free) for mobile. It is a good tool to automate mobile. If your application is web based then you can automate it using selenium in any platform.